# Relation Mapping Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, mapping

In the project I am currenyly working on I stuck on something I have never used mapping etc before so I do not consider myself as project architect but for this project I had to be the architect. Since, I am not very good in the subject I read about it and decided to use code first approach. 
In my project there are 3 tables VALIDATION USER and FILE.

Basicly,
USER table saves the user and password 
FILE table has the image names that were uploaded by the users and those images has to be validated by other users which brings me to VALIDATION table.
In validation table I have the ID, USERID, FILEID to keep the record of who validated what.

One user can validate same image just once.

Here you can see my models

```
public class File
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FILE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool FINAL_IS_VALID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
    public int REQ_COUNT { get; set; }
    public int CUR_COUNT { get; set; }
    public double REQ_PER_CENT { get; set; }
    public double CUR_PER_CENT { get; set; }

    public User USER { get; set; }

    public List<Validation> VALIDATION { get; set; }

    public List<Label> LABEL { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
    public DateTime CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
    public bool IS_ADMIN { get; set; }

    public List<File> FILE { get; set; }

    public List<Validation> VALIDATION { get; set; }
}

public class Validation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IS_VALID { get; set; }
    public DateTime VALIDATION_DATE { get; set; }

    public User USER { get; set; }

    public File FILE { get; set; }
}
```

I did most of my job with this structure. However, when I try to get the files which were not validated by the user I cannot do that with linq.

```
DbObjects.FILE.Include(x => x.USER).Include(x => x.VALIDATION).ThenInclude(x=>x.USER).Where(x => x.FINAL_IS_VALID != true).ToList();
```

in this structure I cannot reach the file.validate.user what shoud I do? 
Is my structure correct or is there better way to do it. I am not sure I understand the mapping perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Take off the first include. You are including the User 2 times.

Comment: okay I did that but when I write 
    DbObjects.FILE.Include(x => x.USER).Include(x => x.VALIDATION).ThenInclude(x=>x.USER).Where(x => x.FINAL_IS_VALID != true && x.VALIDATION.[USER NOT COMES]).ToList(); 
user part does not come after VALIDATION i think it had to be

Comment: Maybe( need to tested) because you are filtering for Not Validation user.

Comment: can you type here an example code please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is clear to you what you want to model.

Every `User` has zero or more `Files`, and every `File` belongs to exactly one `User`. A straightforward one-to-many relationship.

Furthermore: `Files` can be assigned to be `Validated`. This validation is done by one or more `Users`. Such an assignment is called a `Validation`. Every `Validation` is for exactly one `File`, and is done by exactly one `User`. `Users` and `Files` can have several `Validations`: a many-to-many relationship

For a many-to-many relationship we need a junction table. Normally in entity framework you don't have to specify the junction table. Entity Framework will detect the many-to-many relationship and will create the junction table for you.

However, your junction table has some extra columns, among which a property whether the assignment has been completed: `Validation.IsValidated`. That's why you have to specify the junction table.

> In entity framework the columns of a table are represented by
>   non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations
>   between the tables.

I see several places where you deviate from the [entity framework code-first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx).

- First of all, your relations are not declared virtual.
- You also forgot to declare your foreign keys.
- You declared your `many` properties as `List` instead of `ICollection`. Are you sure that `File.Validation[4]` means something?

The improved class definitions, abiding by the conventions

```
class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

   // every User has zero or more Files (one-to-many)
   public virtual ICollection<File> Files {get; set;}

   // every user has zero or more Validations
   public virtual ICollection<Validation> Validations {get; set;}
}

class File
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

   // every File belongs to exactly one User, using foreign key
   public int UserId {get; set;}
   public User User {get; set;}

   // every File has zero or more Validations (one-to-many)
   public virtual ICollection<Validation> Validations {get; set;}
}
```

and Finally the junction table which is in Validations:

```
class Validation
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public bool IsValidated {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every validation belongs to exactly one File, using foreign key
    public int FileId {get; set;}
    public virtual File File {get; set;}

    // every validation belongs to exactly one User, using foreign key
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```

You wrote:

> I try to get the files which were not validated by the user

```
int userId = ...
var fileNotValidatedByUser = myDbContext.Validatin     // from all Validations
    .Where(validation => validation.UserId == userId   // keep the ones from the specified user
                      && !validation.Isvalidated)      // that are not validated yet
    .Select(validation => validation.File)             // from each remaining validation
                                                       // get the File.
};
```

**Query all files that have one or more validations that are not validated yet**

```
var filesNotCompletelyValidated = myDbContext.Files      // from the collection of Files
    .Where(file => file.Validations                      // keep only those files that
           .Where(validation => !validation.IsValidated) // have at least one Validation
           .Any());                                      // that is not Validated yet.
```

**Query all files that were not validated at all**

```
var filesNotCompletelyValidated = myDbContext.Files      // from the collection of Files
    .Where(file => !file.Validations                      // keep only those files that
           .Where(validation => validation.IsValidated)   // that have no Validation
           .Any());                                      // that is Validated.
```

Comment: I will try them as soon as I can. Thank you for your great explanations. I believe they will help me if they will I will let you know. 
"I try to get the files which were not validated by the user" hope I can get them without changing my models

Comment: You don't have to change the database tables. If the names of tables and columns in your classes deviate from the names in the tables, use DbModel.OnModelCreating (fluent API) to correct this. If needed, this is also the place to model your one-to-many and many-to-many relations

Comment: I modified your code as I understand and it did not work for me :/
     DbObjects.VALIDATION.Include(x => x.USER).Include(x=>x.FILE).Where(x => x.USER != user && !x.FILE.FINAL_IS_VALID).Select(x => x.FILE).ToList();
my aim was to get the files which was not validated by this user before I dont know what part is wrong maybe I can try to write direct SQL instead of linq

Comment: First of all: don't use `Include`, use `Select`. `Include` transfers the complete object including the properties you don't intend to use. With `Select` you can exactly fetch the properties you want. Second: your local `user` is of course not equal to the user in the database. They may have same values, but are not same object. Use the Id to test for same user:. `dbContext.Validations.Where(validation => validation.User.Id != user.Id).Select... The result is a collection of validations with their selected properties. In your comment's code you only select the files of a Validation.